# vba get id of selected shape

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to get the id of a selected group-shape after I have just grouped it. But I can't find the right syntax.
Many thanks for your help. 
Here is my current code

```
Dim Ausgabe as Integer
[...]
        If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.count > 1 Then
            ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select
            'Ausgabe = .Shape.Id --> This line does not work ...
            MsgBox (Ausgabe)
        Else
[...]
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a group of shapes selected, you can iterate the `GroupItems` property to get each `Shape` object and its properties:

```
Dim sh As Shape
For Each sh In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.GroupItems
    MsgBox "Shape name: " & sh.Name & ", ID: " & sh.Id
Next
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But I wanted to have the ID of the entire group not of each sigle item within the group. Doesn't it get a new ID the moment it is built. In my code: `ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select`

Comment: I think I have found the right syntax for what I need: `Ausgabe = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Id`

Comment: Now I have a new problem. I want to align to middel the selected shapes before I will group them. How do I do that? `ActiveWindow.Selection.Shapes.selection.align.middle` Many thanks for your help again.